# Can't sign in with FactoryGirl's user/data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot, poltergeist

I have to sign in the user before doing my tests which will use JS. The sign in page does work (except on this test).

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist    

describe "Application", js: true  do
  describe "when logged in", js: true do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      visit signin_path
      fill_in "Email", with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign in"
    end
    it "can authenticate user" do
      User.all.first.authenticate(user.password).email.should == user.email
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that clicking the "Sign in" button returns back to the page with "invalid user/password" combination (as if the user is not in the db). The thing is that apparently the use really IS in the database and the password is right (the test "can authenticate user" passes).

I took a screenshot before clicking the "Sign in" button and the fields are populated correctly. I tried to create the user inside the before block but it didn't work either.

The sign in page doesn't have anything special, no javascript or anything. Just a normal form post to the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this problem while using DeviseInvitable - if an invitation token is set then it won't let that user log in. Don't suppose this applies to you?

Comment: I'm not using Devise but could you please tell me more about your problem and how you solved it? It may give me a clue...

Comment: DeviseInvitable gives users invitation tokens, and if one is set then you can't log in as that user. My Factories were creating users with tokens, and so couldn't log in as them. The error message didn't help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this was happening to me a while ago while using `rspec` and `poltergeist`. The problem was that `phantomjs` thread wasn't able to see the record created by `FactoryGirl` in the db. To solve this problem, you have to configure your db connection to be shared in your `spec_helper.rb` adding the code below.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end

# Forces all threads to share the same connection. This works on
# Capybara because it starts the web server in a thread.
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

You can find more explanation [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/) in the point number 3.

Comment: If you're running spork then you have to put it in the Spork.each_run block of spec_helper.